# Tomcat web.xml to GlassFish 4 web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish, tomcat8, glassfish-4.1

I have a project, which work on Tomcat 8. And I want to run this project on GlassFish 4 server. What I need to do?
How to change web.xml, to run the project on GlassFish?
Or problem not only on web.xml and I need to do anymore?

This is my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>phonebook</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Have you tried running your webapp on GlassFish? Is there a problem? Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, I tried running my web app, and recived 404 error. But new "Hello world" project, which autocreated in Eclipse is starting normally.